# OAuth with Azure AD v2.0: Missing at_hash claim in Azure AD v2.0 id_token

Tags: azure-active-directory

According to the [Azure AD documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens), the Azure AD v2.0 ID Token should contain the access token hash, the `at_hash`claim, when the ID token is issued with the Access Token.

However it appears that the `at_hash` claim is missing from the ID token. After calling the Azure AD access token request v2.0 endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my_tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`, the id_token returned by Azure does not contain a `at_hash` claim although an access token is issued.

Example of response body returned by Azure AD v2.0:

```
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "scope": "User.Read",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "ext_expires_in": 0,
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiO ...",
  "refresh_token": "OAQABAAAAAAA9kTklh ..."
  "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC ..."
```

The id_token contained the following claims.  It did not contain the `at_hash` claim.

```
  "aud": "... GUID ... ",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../v2.0",
  "iat": 1502324474,
  "nbf": 1502324474,
  "exp": 1502328374,
  "aio": "ATQA ... 7liW+Hb",
  "name": "... some name ... ",
  "nonce": "... GUID ...",
  "oid": "... GUID ...",
  "preferred_username": "... some preferred name ...",
  "sub": "KIuLx ... ifCaZUUi3b",
  "tid": "... GUID ...",
  "ver": "2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the request above, you were using the the authorization code flow. It seems that this claim is not issued by this flow. However this claim do issued when requesting using the implicit flow like request below:

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
response_type=token+id_token
&client_id={client_id}
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
&scope=openid+mail.read
&state=123
&nonce=456
```

Comment: According to the [documentation about "Claims in ID token"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens#types-of-tokens): The access token hash is included in ID tokens only when the ID token is issued with an OAuth 2.0 access token.

Since the the purpose of the `at_hash` claim is that the receiver can use it to validate the access token it receives, is there any reason why `at_hash` is not included in the claim when an access token is returned using the authorization code flow?

Comment: This is only based on the test and not able to find the official document about it.